# i want to create a session for login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

```
How can i create a session for a webpage..I was create a webpage with login page.
```

But i was trouble to maintain the user state. please help me to maintain the user status using session or cookies.I you knew please send some sample code to me...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: could you explain with simple program..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain state is asp just by using the session variable available on any page.

```
Session["IsUserLoggedIn"] = true;
Session["CurrentUsername"] = "TestUser";
```

Then you can read these values at a later date. You will need to cast the back to their original types.

```
private void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool?)Session["IsUserLoggedIn"]?? false)
        Response.Write(String.Format("{0} is logged in.", Session["Currentusername"]));
}
```

Note that you should always check that these values are not null before using them.

Comment: How i close the session when linkbutton click..

Comment: You can remove items from the session individually by setting their values to null 'Session["IsUserLoggedIn"] = null;'. You can clear all items in a session by invoking 'Session.Clear();'. Or you can abandon a session alltogether and start a new one by invoking 'Session.Abandon();'.